# story about "souls" of deceased people implanted in other people

Tags: story-identification, souls

This was a novel (rather short if I recall correctly) that I read in the 1990s. For the life of me I can't recall author and title, but I would like to read it again. 
(It might have been a longish short story in a collection, but I think it was a book on its own.)

In a not so far future, people can record their persona (soul) electronically. (The recording is refreshed every few months to keep it up to date.) After they die, this "soul-recording" can be implanted in someone else as a secondary persona. The new host gets access to all knowledge and experience, and for the deceased it is a sort-of afterlife/immortality. The process (recording and implant) is very expensive and thus only available for the wealthy. Having implanted persona becomes a status-symbol. There are dangers: A mismatched between host and implanted persona can lead to schizophrenia or even the implant attempting to take over the host.

As I recall, a powerful business-tycoon (his name is Paul I believe) dies and a struggle erupts between his nephew (who inherited the business) and the biggest competitor. Both want the implant of Paul. If I recall correctly the competitor gets the implant, but the family business is saved by a female family-member (daughter of the nephew? I'm not sure) who manages to get an (illegal) implant of an older backup of Paul.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like ["To Live Again" by Robert Silverberg.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Live_Again_(novel))  It's been a long time since I read it and the summary on Wikipedia doesn't mention the power struggle in your description, but I'm pretty sure that's in the Silverberg book.

Comment: The Goodreads summary matches up even better: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1638070.To_Live_Again

Comment: That's it! Scheffing process, going dybbuk. As soon as I read the synopsis Sean linked to it came back. Thank you both.